# Using coroutines with Android Room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

For about a week now I've been working on adding coroutines to my Room database.  I'm using Googles ViewModels with recyclers that need to update as the database is modified.

I finally got something apparently working but I am new to Android, and Kotlin (6 months) and so I know enough to know I don't know enough and would like to get feedback on any design issues.  I wasn't able to find a simple example that fit my needs but was able to piece this together from what I did find on stack**overflow**, Google, and YouTube.

Main Fragment:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment()
{

   ...
    
    private fun recyclerSetup()
    {
        adapter = MainListAdapter(R.layout.main_list_item)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.main_list_recycler)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
    }
    
    private fun addObservers()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, MyUtils.header0(this, object {}))
        
        viewModel.reminderEntries?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { reminderEntries ->
            adapter?.setReminderEntryList(reminderEntries)
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

*** Edit #1 ***

(Added Adapter Code)

Adapter:

```
class MainListAdapter(private val productItemLayout:Int):RecyclerView.Adapter<MainListAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    private var reminderEntryList:List<ReminderEntry>?=null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, listPosition: Int) {
        val itemQuestion = holder.itemQuestion
        val itemTime = holder.itemCorrectAnswer
        
        reminderEntryList.let {
            val reminderEntry: ReminderEntry = it!![listPosition]

            itemQuestion.text = reminderEntry.question
            itemTime.text = reminderEntry.correctAnser
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
    {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(productItemLayout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    fun setReminderEntryList(reminderEntries:List<ReminderEntry>)
    {
        reminderEntryList = reminderEntries
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if(reminderEntryList==null) 0 else reminderEntryList!!.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        var itemQuestion:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question)
        var itemCorrectAnswer:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.correctAnswer)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
    val repository: Repository = Repository(application)
    
    val debugLogEntries = MutableLiveData<List<DebugLogEntry>>()
    
    
    // ========================================================================
    
    fun insertReminderLogEntry(reminderEntry: ReminderEntry)
    {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertReminderEntry(reminderEntry)
        }
    }
    
    fun deleteAllReminderEntries()
    {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.deleteAllReminderEntries()
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class Repository(application: Application)
{
    var reminderEntries: LiveData<List<ReminderEntry>>?
    
    private var reminderEntryDao: ReminderEntryDao?
    
    init
    {
        val db: MindfulnessDatabase? = MindfulnessDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        reminderEntryDao = db?.reminderEntryDao()
        reminderEntries = reminderEntryDao?.findAllReminderEntries()
    }
    
    // =============================================================================================
    
    suspend fun insertReminderEntry(newDebugLogEntry: ReminderEntry)
    {
        reminderEntryDao?.insertReminderEntry(newDebugLogEntry)
    }
    
    suspend fun findAllReminderEntries(): LiveData<List<ReminderEntry>>?
    {
        return reminderEntryDao?.findAllReminderEntries()
    }
    
    suspend fun deleteAllReminderEntries()
    {
        reminderEntryDao?.deleteAllReminderEntries()
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ReminderEntryDao
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM bluetooth_event_table")
    fun findAllReminderEntries():LiveData<List<ReminderEntry>>
    
    @Insert
    @Transaction
    suspend fun insertReminderEntry(reminderEntry: ReminderEntry?)

    @Query("DELETE FROM bluetooth_event_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllReminderEntries()
}
```

I'm still quite new to stack**overflow** so if anything in my question needs clarification please ask in the comments.

Comment: I can see that you have ViewModel observer notifying your adaptor.  Are you telling you'r adaptor `notifyDataSetChanged()` within the `Adapter?.setReminderEntryList(reminderEntries)` method?

Comment: Sorry, forgot my Adapter...  Yes I do.  I added the adapter code to the question.  It apparently works, so I'm mainly concerned about unobvious problems such as memory leaks and such...

Comment: I added the Adapter to the question

Comment: I thought I had added the Adapter code yesterday but it wasn't there today so I readded it

Comment: I don't see any issues.  It clearly laid out Android recommended MVVM design.